# getting value from QSpinBox created in a QFormLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering how to refer to the `QSpinBox` s I created with the code

```
     QFormLayout* layout = new QFormLayout;
     layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Board Size")), new QSpinBox);
     layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Number of \nStarting Moves")), new QSpinBox);
     layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Seed Value")), new QSpinBox);
```

This is in a `void` function that creates a form layout, applies it to a QWidget `f` and then sets `f` as the widget for a QDockWidget that is added to a QMainWindow.

I then need to use the values in the `QSpinBox`s for running another function, but I have no clue how to differentiate between or reference the boxes.  I know `QSpinBox`s have a `value()` function, but how do I call that on each different box?

Sorry if I am using Qt in an unusual manner, I am new to Qt programming. Also, I do not want to use any visual programming, I want to code everything.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all - creating widgets without specifying parent is a potential memory leak, so you shouldn't do it, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Second of all, if you want to use some value in your class - you should make a pointer to it a member of your class and address to it by name (like [Aliceljm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1596799/aliceljm) did).

Also, you can use `void QFormLayout::addRow ( const QString & labelText, QWidget * field )` in order, not to create labels manually (if you don't need direct access to them).

Summing all above, your final code should contain:

Widget.h

```
protected:
    QSpinBox *mBoardSizeSpinBox;
    QSpinBox *mNumberOfMovesSpinBox;
    QSpinBox *mSpeedValueSpinBox;
```

Widget.cpp

```
mBoardSizeSpinBox = new QSpinBox(this);
mNumberOfMovesSpinBox = new QSpinBox(this);
mSpeedValueSpinBox = new QSpinBox(this);

QFormLayout* layout = new QFormLayout(this);
layout->addRow(tr("Board Size"), mBoardSizeSpinBox);
layout->addRow(tr("Number of \nStarting Moves"), mNumberOfMovesSpinBox);
layout->addRow(tr("Seed Value"), mSpeedValueSpinBox);

// ... using

int speedValue = mSpeedValueSpinBox->value();
```

Comment: Adding widget to layout will set parent

Comment: Yes, I remember reading about it some time. But, while writing this answer, I looked through Qt's help and didn't find this information. Anyway, I truly believe, that in a good code you should specify parent of `QObject` inheritor (unless you *really* don't need your object to have a parent).

Comment: It's actually says about ownership of QLayoutItem, not QWidget. Nevertheless I found this information here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts Indeed, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do like this:

```
    QSpinBox *spinbox1=new QSpinBox;
spinbox1->setRange(1,100);
QSpinBox *spinbox2=new QSpinBox;
QSpinBox *spinbox3=new QSpinBox;

QFormLayout* layout = new QFormLayout;
layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Board Size")), spinbox1);
layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Number of \nStarting Moves")), spinbox2);
layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Seed Value")), spinbox3);

qDebug()<< spinbox1->value();
```

A pointer can get spinbox value everywhere

Answer (score 0):

This is your code.

```
    void Test::createForm()
{
QFormLayout* layout = new QFormLayout;
layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Board Size")), new QSpinBox);
layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Number of \nStarting Moves")), new QSpinBox);
layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Seed Value")), new QSpinBox);

QDockWidget *dockWidget =  new QDockWidget();
QWidget* widget = new QWidget(  );
widget->setLayout( layout );
dockWidget->setWidget( widget );
dockWidget->show();
addDockWidget(  Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dockWidget );
}
```

This is your other function, where you wanted to get the reference of spinbox.

```
void Test::referSpinBox()

{
```

/* to reach the reference of spinbox, you have to first get the dockwidget, then widget, then layout then 
           find exact row and colum then you will reach on spinbox
         See it is too complicated, Qt is great, it simply not provide any API to get the DockWidget what you added in the mainwindow( except tabifiedDockWidgets API ).
         so that means, you have to change implemention logic, above replayed answers are correct.  that is the way of approach, note that, the concept of signal/slot is play a big role to access the spibox in another function.*/

```
}
```

Signal/slot will be used to solve this.
Please use above answer posted with this code

```
QObject::connect( mBoardSizeSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged ( int  )), this, SLOT(YourAnotherSlot( int    )));
```

your slot.

```
void Test::YourAnotherSlot( int )
{
//can access here.
mBoardSizeSpinBox->value();
}
```